# tableau is using unidentified source

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I am using extract to view a workbook in tableau server.

I deleted the local extract as well as the extract in the server.

I am still able to see that data is being pointed.

Struggled a lot to understand this.Does tableau create temp folder to store?
FYI It is not in live mode(since the data is not being changed until I refresh).

How do I point to server extract?(is it automatic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a workbook on Server is pointing to a server hosted data source and that data source is delete, then it would not render. If you're still able to view the data, then it sounds like the workbook was uploaded with the extract. Check the file size, if it's large, that's probably what happened.

Comment: The workbook has an extract.
But when it is uploaded it was uploaded as .twb file(only workbook).
I have extracted a local copy(.tde) and also published the data on server.
So is the data pointing to local or server?

Comment: The file type of the workbook when published is irrelevant. If the workbook uses an extract data source that is unpublished, then the extract will be pushed to Tableau Server as an embedded data source when the workbook is published. This type of data source is only removed when the workbook itself is deleted.